# how to clean install sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

i want to install sqlite via "npm install sqlite3" on my visual studio project.
But for no reason I got an error.

i am using node 16.14.2 and npm 8.5.0

I tried to install an specific version of sqlite3 via "npm install sqlite3@x.x.x" but this does not work at all. So I come up with the idea to uninstall sqlite from my Mac system and reinstall it.
When I check the installed Version of sqlite in terminal I got this :

```
  3.37.0 2021-12-09 01:34:53 9ff244ce0739f8ee52a3e9671adb4ee54c83c640b02e3f9d185fd2f9a179aapl
```

when I try to uninstall it with "npm uninstall sqlite3" and check again the Version, I got the same output.

This is the error in Visual Studio:

```
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-darwin-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.2 and node@16.14.2 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-darwin-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/kaan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.2/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/kaan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/kaan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
npm ERR! /bin/sh: python: command not found
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3340000/sqlite3.c] Error 127
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/kaan/Desktop/JS/reservieren/main/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all that got the same issue:
for me it worked when I installed an older version of node (like 15.0.0) with `nvm install 15.0.0` and then installing sqlite3 on my project.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`npm uninstall sqlite3`

`npm cache clean`

`npm install sqlite3`

Comment: npm cache clean does not work I will get an error but I tried "npm cache verify" instead. When I run the command to install sqlite3 again I got the same error

Comment: yeah so you tried `nvm install 15.0.0` its working right now?